# Why setStyle does not work for point?

Tags: openlayers

I have a feature. The feature has `geometry: Point`. I try to change a style:

```
  const selectPointStyle = new Style({
      image: new Circle({
        radius: 45,
        fill: new Fill({ color: '#000000' }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: [255, 0, 0],
          width: 2,
        }),
      }),
      zIndex: 900,
    });


    feature.setStyle(selectPointStyle);
```

But there is not effect. What do I do wrong?

Also I tried this style for Point:

```
const selectPointStyle = new Style({
  image: new Icon({
    scale: 0.5,
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    color: '#000000',
    src: `assets/images/point.svg`,
  }),
  zIndex: 10000,
});
```

Can be reason is that points inside cluster?

The relevant part of source and layer:

```
 drawPointLayer(layer: LayerNode) {
    const { id } = layer;

    if (!this.vectorLayers.has(id)) {
      const { icon, zIndex } = layer;
      const layerConfig = this.getLayerConfig(id);

      const source = new VectorSource({
        format: new GeoJSONOl(),
        loader: (extent: Extent, resolution: number, projection) => {
          const url =
            this.configService.config.backendurl + `tile?layers=${id}`;
          this.http
            .get(url, { withCredentials: true })
            .pipe(filter(Boolean))
            .subscribe((response) => {
              for (const [, geojson] of Object.entries(response)) {
                const geoJSONFormat = new GeoJSONOl();
                const features = geoJSONFormat.readFeatures(geojson);
                source.addFeatures(features);
              }
            });
        },
        strategy: bboxStrategy,
      });

      source.on('addfeature', (e: VectorSourceEvent) =>
        addfeatureCallback(e.feature, layer, layerConfig)
      );

      const clusterSource = new Cluster({
        distance: this.configService.config.distanceCluster ?? 100,
        source,
      });

      const clusterVector = new VectorLayer({
        source: clusterSource,
        style: (feature) =>
          styleIconFeatureFunction(feature, icon, {}, this.baseHref),
      });

      if (zIndex) clusterVector.setZIndex(zIndex);
      this.mapService.map.addLayer(clusterVector);
      this.pointLayersSource.set(layer, source);
      this.addVectorLayer(id, clusterVector);
    }
  }
```

Comment: There's a lot of relevant code and info missing to give you an answer.

Comment: What part of code do you need?

Comment: Whatever part is relevant to your question: sources, layers, ...

Comment: I have added th relevant part of layer and source